# Incidence of Special Characters inserted in MongoDB "? string:592ea246b2bafaeedd04eef6 ?"

Tags: android, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

In the app  Mongo DB and SpringData are used to do the CRUD operations.There are cases where some special characters are inserted. 
For Example:
Let's say there are Main Id and SubId inserted into a collection. And Main Id is fetched using subId.
e.g "SubId" : "592ea246b2bafaeedd04eef6"
I fetch the mainId using sub id and insert those values into another collection.
There are some cases where I have records such as

```
"SubId" : "? string:592ea246b2bafaeedd04eef6 ?",
    "MainId " : "? object:null ?"
```

There might string format issues but at code level there are no issues as such. No idea why this is happening. Help me find out the root cause as I am not able to reproduce this issue at will.